# How to make a glowing bar effect in iOS like the one used when personal hotspot is on?

Tags: ios, user-interface, ios4, uikit

I'd like to use this effect (not necessarily blue) when I'm synching my app to my server. I've searched the interwebs and apple dev forums but to no avail.

[image: Glowing top Bar when Hotspot is enabled.]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the effect, you just want to make the background color of a view change? `backgroundColor` can be animated.

Comment: @bishirley not exactly. The top bar shown in the image has a distinct glow effect. This is also shown when you're recording with Voice Memo app but in read. Skype app also uses this when your connection is slow.

Comment: by "glow" do you mean the color changes, or the color is not consistent across the whole area.  If the later, you can put a partially transparent grayscale image in the background, and change the color of the background to give you that.  the status bar is set to transparent, of course

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this (though it gives you very little control over how the double status bar looks) is to simulate an audio session. See the following question & answer: [SBStatusBarController instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246306/sbstatusbarcontroller-instance/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this nicely as Apple does this. There are two ways to do at least something close to this:

- You can try to set status bar style to UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent and plea a little bit with background images under the status bar that will affect a color a little bit.
- You can take a look through the code by following links — http://www.cocoabyss.com/uikit/custom-status-bar-ios/ and https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay/ this two code samples implements an overlay above the status bar that fools a user. Achieved result maybe pretty close to what you show in your screenshot.