# Show green bar on top of screen to return to app

Tags: iphone, ios, voip, twilio, info.plist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SBStatusBarController instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246306/sbstatusbarcontroller-instance)

I am working on voip based application, i have used "Twilio Api" for this.
Every thing works fine but when my goes in background when call is going on, my call is interrupted and iphone does not show green bar on top of screen to return to app.
To display green bar and run call in background i have set "voip value in my info.plist" file.

Is there any suggestion??

Thanks..

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7283146/1445205

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your app is not a voip or audio app, apple wont like this

but it works using a plist key. see: [SBStatusBarController instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246306/sbstatusbarcontroller-instance/7283146#7283146)