# iOS: Show blue bar for active navigation

Tags: ios, background, navigation, navigationbar

[image]

I'd like to display this blue bar, while my App is running in background.

How can I do that?

Maik

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for the the SBStatusBar - it's (I think) a private API to access and show it. However, there are non-private ways you can get it to appear. Check out the following link : [SBStatusBarController instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246306/sbstatusbarcontroller-instance/)

Comment: hm, couldn't find a way to get the blue bar :-/

Answer (score 0):

You access your location even in background and request a permission for location in `"requestWhenInUseAuthorization"` means blue bar indicates your app access your location it is from `ios8`